# How to bind Artifactory to localhost only?

Tags: artifactory

According to [Artifactory documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/HTTP+Settings),

> For best security, when using Artifactory behind a reverse proxy, it must be co-located on the same machine as the web server, and Artifactory should be explicitly and exclusively bound to localhost.

How can I configure Artifactory so that it is bound to localhost only?

Comment: What artifactory version are you referring to? 6.x or 7.x?

Comment: We use Artifactory 7.12.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Artifactory version `7.12.x`, there are two endpoints exposed for accessing the application:

- Port 8082 - all the Artifactory services (UI + API) via the JFrog router
- Port 8081 - direct to the Artifactory service API running on Tomcat (for better performance)

The JFrog Router does not support specific binding configuration today.
Tomcat can controlled with setting a custom `address="127.0.0.1"` on the relevant connector.

Your best bet would be to simply close all ports on the server running your Artifactory and allow only entry to the web server's port. This is best practice anyway for security aware systems.

**IMPORTANT:**

If using other JFrog products like [JFrog Xray](https://jfrog.com/xray/) or [JFrog Pipelines](https://jfrog.com/pipelines/), they rely on direct access to the Artifactory router, so your security rules should take that into consideration.

You can find a map of all JFrog platform ports on the [official Wiki page](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/System+Requirements#SystemRequirements-RequirementsMatrix).

**EDIT:**

As of Artifactory 7.37.0, it's also possible to bind JFrog Router's port 8082 to localhost only with the `system.yaml` config

```
router:
  entrypoints:
    externalHost: localhost
```

You can see the official [Artifactory system.yaml](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/artifactory-system-yaml) docs.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat for Artifactory can be controlled via system.yaml file. Even if changes are made to the server.xml file, they will be overwritten when the application is restarted
You could controll access for artifactory using following systax in system.yaml file:

```
 tomcat:
        connector:
            maxThreads: 400
            sendReasonPhrase: true
            relaxedPathChars: '"[]"'
            relaxedQueryChars: '"[]"'
            extraConfig: "address='localhost'"
```